# What are some alternatives to using a cursor in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, data-import

I've been creating imports that use SSIS to import data into a temp table, then using a stored procedure, steps through the data one by one with a cursor to process the data and insert information into 3 different tables.  The inserts in the first 2 tables are complicated because if there is a record that already exists with the same data the record is not created.  Whether the a record is inserted or not in the first 2 tables the ID of the record or matching record is returned to be used on the 3rd table.  Is there an alternative to using the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your current code it is difficult to know whether this would be  suitable but I'd look at

1. the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement (allows actions to be specified for the different cases "when matched", "when not matched by target", "when not matched by source") and
2. the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause (allows you to capture the newly updated records for processing).

Comment: I'll try MERGE.  I've never used it before.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully some ideas from this will help. If you still need help avoiding a cursor, we need to see a better example of the processing you are doing in the cursor.

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect candidate for replacing a cursor with a combination of table variables and a while loop (which, multiple people have tested and confirmed, is nearly always more performant than a cursor).